# Global variable in Python changed by multiple functions

Tags: python, global-variables

I want to create a global variable inside a class method and then change it by other functions. This is my code:

```
def funcA():
    global x
    print(x)
    x = 2
    a = funcB()
    return x
    
def funcB():
    global x
    print(x)
    x = 4
    return 2
    
    
class A():
    def method():
        x = 0
        return funcA()

A.method()
```

So I create variable `x` inside class method and then in all other methods which uses this variable I wrote `global x`. Unfortunately it doesn't work. What should I change? `funcA` should print 0, `funcB` should print 2 and the final results should be 4.

Comment: "in other methods which use this variable" - *no* other methods use the local variable `x` defined in `A.method`. They are using a global variable with the same name.

Comment: So why didn't you write `global x` inside `A.method()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, use of global variables is frowned upon. If you see that a group of methods all need to manipulate the same variable it is often a sign that you actually want a class. You are on the right track trying to define the class, but unfortunately the syntax is a little more complicated

Here is one suggestion:

```
class A:
    
    def method(self):
        self.x = 0  # note use of self, to refer to the class instance
        return self.funcA()

    def funcA(self):
        print(self.x)
        self.x = 2
        self.funcB()
        
    def funcB(self):
        print(self.x)
        self.x = 4
        
a = A() # making an instance of A
a.method() # calling the method on the instance
print(a.x) # showing that x has become 4
```

Answer (score 0):

create the variable globally. just add x = 0 at the starting of your code, it will work

Answer (score 0):

```
x = 0
def funcA():
    global x
    print(x)
    x = 2
    a = funcB()
return x

def funcB():
    global x
    print(x)
    x = 4
    return 2

class A():
    def method():
        return funcA()

print(A.method())
```

It should work now, the problem was that you declared x inside class A, so it wasn't global.